# How to stop requests from being sent to my API

Tags: cypress

I am using `cy.intercept` to verify requests made to an API.

Whilst asserts are working great an issue is that my requests are actually sent to an API.

So, what do I do to stop actual requests from being sent to an API?

This is what I am doing right now:

```
cy.intercept('api/login', []).as('login')

cy.get('[data-cy=login]')
  .click()
  .wait('@login')
  .its('request')
  .then(({ headers, body }) => {
    // perform asserts...
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to reply from the intercept instead of the API is to use `cy.intercept(url, staticResponse)` where the simplest staticResponse is an empty object `{}`,

```
cy.intercept('api/login', {}).as('login')
```

Obviously if your app needs some properties in the response, you should add those, or use a fixture, etc

Ref [StaticResponse objects](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#StaticResponse-objects).

Comment: Both {} and [] work fine. What I didn't realize is that we had another endpoint call being made performed similar action